# Issue with the change of the column precision to be 2 decimal places

Tags: sql

I need to change the % sales vs forecast column precision to be 2 decimal places instead of whole numbers. The confusing part is that I already have a format function and 'Po' as a '%" at the end, so I am trying to understand how I can make a % with two decimal points keeping this '%' sign in the field as well.

My formula:

FORMAT((f.TOTHIST - f.TOTFCST) / f.TOTFCST, 'P0') AS 'Sales VS FCST'

How I have now

[image]

If someone can help me how to adjust it and make it for example in the result as 48.88% instead of 49% that would be great!

Thank you!!

Comment: Don’t store the formatted value - eg including the “%”, in the DB, because that’s a rendering issue. If you absolutely must render it in the query (a poor choice), format the column in-query. The best way is the let the reporting tool handle rendering

Comment: Can you try this `SELECT FORMAT((f.TOTHIST - f.TOTFCST) / f.TOTFCST,'#,##0.0%')`?

Comment: @Salvino thank you!! The only thing your formula gave me only one decimal point and I need two so I added one zero at the end, is that fine? FORMAT((f.TOTHIST - f.TOTFCST) / f.TOTFCST,'#,##0.00%') ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. @JeremyU. Did you check the output? Is it fine?

Comment: @Salvino yes, I think it is fine. Thank you!!

Comment: @JeremyU please accept the answer so that it may help others in future who stumble on the same issue.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format works fine:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT((f.TOTHIST - f.TOTFCST) / f.TOTFCST,'#,##0.00%')
```